# Remove Event Listener "keydown" from ExtJS slider

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using in my project slider Class from ExtJS. Me on the onkeypress event to perform some action. Everything would have been nice if it were not for slider. He also uses the event only onkeypress. Question: how to delete this event? I have tried in terms of the .mun - it did not work. Any Ideas?

Example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/3ZLFV/32/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitely setting the onkeypress event handler for the slider and having it simply return true?  This should allow natural event propogation to take place.

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery

```
$('#slider').unbind();
```